# Simplifying Hypergeometric Function

Tags: simplifying-expressions, special-functions

```
thissum = Sum[2^k n/(n - k) Binomial[n - k, 2 k], {k, 0, n/3}];
```

*Mathematica* finds:

```
HypergeometricPFQ[{1/3 - n/3, 2/3 - n/3, -(n/3)}, {1/2, 1 - n}, 27/2]
```

In fact the sum has the simple closed form expression: $2^{n-1}+\cos(n \pi/2)$.
Try it!

If I use `FullSimplify` and specify that `n` is a positive integer it returns `ComplexInfinity`. How can I get *Mathematica* to give the simpler answer?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Writing:

```
Sum[2^k n/(n - k) Binomial[n - k, 2 k] // FunctionExpand, {k, 0, n/3}] // ComplexExpand
```

I get:

```
2^(-1 + n) + Cos[(n \[Pi])/2]
```

which is what you want.

Answer (score 6):

Just in case for the next time it pays to have several methods. Here is a different way:

```
Table[Sum[2^k n/(n - k) Binomial[n - k, 2 k], {k, 0, n/3}], {n, 3, 39,3}]
FindSequenceFunction[%, n] // ComplexExpand

{4, 31, 256, 2049, 16384, 131071, 1048576, 8388609, 67108864, \
536870911, 4294967296, 34359738369, 274877906944}

2^(-1 + 3 n) + Cos[(n \[Pi])/2]
```

Comment: This is interesting but it isn't giving the correct solution. If you change the enumerations in the table from {n,3,39,3} to {n,1,8} it gives the correct answer.

Comment: Hi JEP; I left it that way on purpose. Due to the way FindSequenceFunction fits this uses 1,2,3,4,5... instead of your 3,6,9,12... I think it makes more sense to count by ones instead of threes. But it is a simple matter to change it back.